# Setting Default values In Classes in Java

Tags: java

```
class Test {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    Test(int x, int y, int z) {
        a += x;
        b += y;
        c += z;
    }
}

class Ak {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test(10, 20, 30);
        Test t2 = new Test(1, 1, 1);
        System.out.println(t2.a + " " + t2.b + " " + t2.c);
    }
}
```

This is My Code what I actually trying to do is.I set value of t1 i.e. 10,20,30.Now When I create another Object I want to Add Those Value with the value of object of previous one.

Example, in this case, My Values in t1 are 10,20,30 
My values in t2 are 1,1,1
So now If I Show the output for t2.a,t2.b,t2.c , Instead of showing values as 1,1,1 I want them to be added to values of the Previous object i.e. 10,20,30.So when I show values of my t2.a,t2.b,t2.c It came as 11,21,31.

Comment: Please format code, i.e. indent it for human readability.

Comment: make a, b and c static

Comment: Don't do what you're trying to do. As Juan said, to get that result, you make the fields `static`, but you shouldn't create objects and then have constructor store all the values in global memory. The point of creating objects is to have object-specific values. What you're trying to do is misguided. More specifically, once you make fields `static`, there is no such thing as `t2.a`, although the compiler won't complain. There is only `Test.a`. Compiler silently changes `t1.a` and `t2.a` to `Test.a`, which means your code is misleading.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry I didn't know much about this,This question was given to me by my teacher.I tried a lot and failed many times and then posted this question.He told to manipulate value of 1st object with value of 2nd object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share the values of the fields between instances of one class, you should use static fields.

In your example would be:

```
static int a = 0;
static int b = 0;
static int c = 0;
```

Note: In this case there would be no difference between

`System.out.println(t2.a +" "+ t2.b +" "+t2.c);`

and

`System.out.println(t1.a +" "+ t1.b +" "+t1.c);`
as they share the field values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep both objects separated you should make another function in order to plus the results of the first object, or just override the constructor function, as you can make more than one if you change the number of parameters on that one:

```
Test(Test previous, int a, int b, int c){
  Test res = new Test(previous.a, previous.b, previous.c);
  res.a+=a;
  res.b+=b;
  res.c+=c;
  return res;
}
```

That should make it to solve your problem.